# How to push multiple objects in array using $push (Mongoose)

Tags: arrays, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Having a lot of trouble pushing multiple objects into an array.

I've tried several different variations of this code, and I either end up pushing the objects directly to the db, or only pushing the last object of the array

Here is the code I'm trying currently, which works, but only pushes the last object (in this case wednesday).

```
  collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: 'yyy' }, 
  { $push: { schedule: monday, schedule: tuesday, schedule: wednesday}},
 function (error, success) {
       if (error) {
           console.log("error");
           console.log(error);
       } else {
           console.log("success");
           console.log(success);
       }
});
```

I've tried

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: 'yyy' }, 
  { $push: { schedule: monday, tuesday, wednesday}}
```

and it just pushed tuesday and wednesday to the main instead of placing them in the schedule array.

Here is the schema i'm using for schedule

```
  schedule: [
    {
        day: { type: String, default: ""},
        closed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        start: { type: Number, default: 0},
        startap: { type: String, default: "AM"},
        end: { type: Number, default: 0},
        endap: { type: String, default: "PM"}
    }
  ]
```

Heres and example of the day variables i want to push to the schedule array

```
var monday = { 
            day:"Monday", 
            closed: false, 
            start:"700", 
            startap:"AM", 
            end:"1900", 
            endap:"PM"
};
```

Obviously I could just run the fine and update code 7 times, but I feel like theres a more efficient way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [Append Multiple Values to an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array) by using `$push` with `$each`.
Example:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: 'yyy' }, 
  { $push: { schedule: {$each: [monday, tuesday, wednesday]}}}...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$push` with the `$each` modifier to append multiple values to the array field.

The following example appends each element of `[ 90, 92, 85 ]` to the scores array for the document where the name field equals joe:

```
db.students.updateOne(
   { name: "joe" },
   { $push: { scores: { $each: [ 90, 92, 85 ] } } }
)
```